# NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open:

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have just downloaded the tensorflow version of Google-research Bert in GitHub. After modifying run_classifier.py, I typed the following command in the cmd but it seems something goes wrong. I run the code in windows 10 and version of python is 3.6, is this the problem?

```
(tensorflowgpu) D:\pyproject\bert-master\bert-master>python run_classifier.py --data_dir=/dataset/ --task_name=zw --vocab_file=/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/vocab.txt --bert_config_file=/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json --do_train=true --do_eval=true --init_checkpoint=/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert.model.ckpt --max_seq_length=128 --train_batch_size=32 --learning_rate=5e-5 --num_train_epochs=10.0 --do_predict=true --output_dir=/tmp/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_classifier.py", line 1018, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\zhiwei\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "run_classifier.py", line 837, in main
    bert_config = modeling.BertConfig.from_json_file(FLAGS.bert_config_file)
  File "D:\pyproject\bert-master\bert-master\modeling.py", line 94, in from_json_file
    text = reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\zhiwei\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\zhiwei\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "C:\Users\zhiwei\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: /chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json : ϵͳ\udcd5Ҳ\udcbb\udcb5\udcbdָ\udcb6\udca8\udcb5\udcc4·\udcbe\udcb6\udca1\udca3
; No such process
```

Comment: I don't know about the gibberish at the end of the error message, but "not found" indicates that likely, the path to the file is incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean the bert_config.json path is wrong? But I have checked and there is no problem about that:). Is it possible to have access denied?

Comment: It could be a permission problem (in which TensorFlow needs to improve its error message: `NotFoundError` is bad already here, when it fails to *create* or open a file; besides the point). But if you run this as normal user and are able to create files in that directory, and the bert_config.json file, I don't know.

Comment: Do, however, try with standard Windows *back*slashes, instead of *nix-style forward slashes. Ideally, Python internally handles this correctly, but TensorFlow may just mess this up.